# Ionic 2 SplitPane changing sass variables not working

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I’m using split-pane component and want to change the min-width and max-width of the left panel according to my requirements .

For this I’m changing the the provided sass variables for SplitPane from ionic docs in the `variables.scss` file.

[image]

but the change is not reflected in the `main.css` file after doing ionic serve.

[image]

First I thought it could be problem with sass but I changed another variable called `@background-color` and it worked .

Please can anyone help with this?

Here is the ionic info

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.1.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.2.0

System:

    Node : v6.11.1
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/)

By default, SplitPane will expand when the screen is larger than 768px. If you want to customize this, use the when input. The when input can accept any valid media query, as it uses matchMedia() underneath.

```
<ion-split-pane when="(min-width: 475px)">

  <!--  our side menu  -->
  <ion-menu [content]="content">
  ....
  </ion-menu>

  <!-- the main content -->
  <ion-nav [root]="root" main #content></ion-nav>
</ion-split-pane>
```

You can also customize it in your code

```
<ion-split-pane [when]="shouldShow()">
...
</ion-split-pane>
class MyClass {
  constructor(){}
  shouldShow(){
    if(conditionA){
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```